# How to set item in 2D list in Flask Template

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I know to set a variable in a flask template, you do something `{% set var = val %}`, but if you need to set a specific item of a list, how can you do that?

Everytime I do something like this: `{% set lst[0][0] = val %}`, it gives me an error saying `"TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got '['"`

It seems like Jinja doesn't accept this syntax, and I've tried to iterate through the individual list doing for loops like so:

```
{% for item in lst %}
  {% set item = someVal %}
{% endfor %}
```

When I do this, the list `lst` doesn't update and I don't know how to update the list through the Flask syntax. Any help is appreciated. I'm using Python 2.7 and Jinja 2.

Comment: you should create list with all data in function before you send it to template.

Comment: the main question is why you need it. It seems strage that you assing something in template. You should preper all in function.

Comment: Isn't the `{% set %}` command made for that functionality though?

Comment: isn't `function` made for prepering all data before you use template ?

Comment: Yes, but what if one needs to interact with the data?